# Getting the force somehow using magneticfield force (tesla)

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

First off, sorry if not everything makes sense, english isn't my first language so some scientific terms may sound weird if they're in English. For a project we are making a coil gun. So we get a straight magnetic field where B is in 1 direction. I wanna model this so i can see what is the best possible measurements for us. Taking in acount the length of the coil, the wire thickness and length etc. But i already came into the problem. To get the max speed i'll use a=F/m then v=a*t. But how am i gonna get the F in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. Actually, the analysis is much easier just using conservation of energy instead of $F = ma$. But the problem is that any ‘simple’ analysis assumes that:

- The projectile is not affected by friction.
- The coupling between the coils and the projectile is perfect, i. e. all the energy that is discharged on the coil at the moment of pulling the trigger would be transferred to the projectile.
- There isn't any dissipation on the circuit (no parasitic resistance) and on the projectile (no eddy currents).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coilgun) you can red that:

> Ideally, 100% of the magnetic flux generated by the coil would be delivered to and act on the projectile; in reality this is impossible due to energy losses always present in a real system, which cannot be eliminated.
>
> \With a simple air-cored solenoid, the majority of the magnetic flux is not coupled into the projectile because of the magnetic circuit's high reluctance. The uncoupled flux generates a magnetic field that stores energy in the surrounding air. The energy that is stored in this field does not simply disappear from the magnetic circuit once the capacitor finishes discharging, instead returning to the coilgun's electric circuit. Because the coilgun's electric circuit is inherently analogous to an LC oscillator, the unused energy returns in the reverse direction ('ringing'), which can seriously damage polarized capacitors such as electrolytic capacitors.

However, in the same article is presented the equation of exit speed, which arises from the conservation of energy:

$$v_o = \sqrt{\frac{2}{m} V \mu_0 \chi_m n^2 I}$$

Where $v_o$ is the exit speed of the projectile, $m$ the mass, $V$ the volume, $\mu_0$ the vacuum permeability, $\chi_m$ the magnetic susceptibility of the body, $n$ the number of turns of the coil and $I$ its current. In magnetic systems always there are many factors that must be taken into account, which usually produce a behavior that is far from ideal. So don't be surprised if there's a huge difference between that equation and the measured speed.

Pro tip: if you can get a numerical (FEM) simulator, and input the dimensions and intrinsic properties of the coil and projectile and the initial conditions of the circuit. Then you might predict with a more sophisticated model that those who reduce everything to a single equation.